# Is an implicit GCHandle released when the function returns?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Public Sub exampleSub()


     Dim temp As IntPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(New IntPtr, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject()

     'other stuff


End Sub
```

Will`temp` be released at the `End Sub`? Will this sub cause any memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't, you have to release it manually, hopefully with a `Try`/`Finally`.